# anybody know how to choose the mnumber of paremetrs passed on a method in python

Tags: python, oop, parameters

class filler (object):

```
def init(self, you):
    self.you = you

def Family(self, sibling, ):
    pass
```

where the user can decide how many siblings they have

I know this is probably a stupid question but I am a beginner and any help is appreciated

Comment: You can also pass a reference to list/dict of objects, like passing `siblings` instead.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
def Family(self, *args):
    pass
```

You can then iterate over args like this

```
def Family (*args):
    for sibling in args:
        print(sibling)
```